# Can we send notifications in android using Firebase's UID instead of registration token?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have two android applications in my single firebase project. That project belongs to the connection of vehicles. One app is for the driver and other app is for the passenger. So whenever passenger requests for a ride the driver needs to be notified of that request. So is there any way to send notification to the driver using firebase UID instead of FCM registration token.

I want to know whether registration token will be fix for a particular user or it will refresh/change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, use this to register the UID as a topic:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
                .subscribeToTopic(appUser.getUid());
```

Now, when sending the notification, you can use this topic to send the notif. to the particular user.

Tokens keep on refreshing at instances, topics defined by you will not change. Every device for which the topic is defined will be notified.

> **NOTE:**
>
> Registering too many topics will raise
>   `messaging/too-many-topics` error. [Details here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference) Hence, token
>   registration in the preferred  way.

Fetching and keeping track of tokens:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    // Save the new token here in a place from where you want to fetch it and send notification
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Subscribing too many topics might throw ```messaging/too-many-topics:- A registration token has been subscribed to the maximum number of topics and cannot be subscribed to any more.```. Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference)

Comment: That is true. I just suggested a method.

Comment: Thanks @YashKrishanVerma , if register tokens change over time then how to keep track of particular user in firebase. Is there any method fix this issue?

Comment: Just simply save the tokens and you them to send notification.

Comment: @Aziz I want to have access each user in firebase instead of their device registration token. Is there any way? Or is there any way to use this registration token in such a way that we can get the target account to send the notification.

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma ok .. I will check that. May I know how long registration token  will be there. I want a time till which the registration token is alive. So that when the registration token is destroyed, I can update the new registration token.

Comment: Token is renewed when user clears app data or uninstall/reinstall it. I am adding a code to keep track of renewed token

Comment: Thanks @YashKrishanVerma for clearing my doubt. Can you get me the code to keep track of renewed token?

Comment: You need to put this in MyFirebaseMessagingService or whatever name you've given to the FCM class.

Comment: I can't able to find the code.? where will be the code?

Comment: I've added it in my answer. Refresh this page if you can't see it.

Comment: OK Cool. Thanks.. @YashKrishanVerma

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `No`. The FCM tokens are device generated tokens which is generated when,

- App is installed
- App Data is cleared

and `UID` is a unique identification generated from a particular user account. Both are not related to each other.

As per your problem, you need to store your tokens wrt to UID and then use it to send notification. Or you can use subscribe tokens for seperate user group. Thats the only option I see.

Comment: Can you please tell more about subscribe tokens for separate user group. Thanks..

Comment: Subscribe topic comes into play when like you said, driver and the passenger has separate apps/account and you want to send only to all driver but not the passenger. So, you need to subscribe to "driver" or "passenger" whichever may be the case, to send it to separate groups.

Comment: Can you guys please tell me how to send the notification using code and not from the firebase console. I am stuck on how to send the notification using java code rather than sending using the firebase console.

Comment: You have to setup `Firebase Cloud Functions`. [Here](https://github.com/azizur-rehman/SSTalk/blob/master/Cloud%20Script/index.js) is a script just in case you needed it. It has the trigger that sends notification whenever there is a change in the respected node.

Comment: How to set up Firebase Cloud Functions? And the script you shared with me is in Javascript. I am coding in java.

Comment: Cloud Functions are generally written in either `Typescript` or `Javascript`